# pandas: convert string column to array of float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a the following df:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'feature_idx': ['(4,)','(4, 15)','(1, 4, 15)',
  '(1, 4, 15, 176)','(1, 4, 15, 89, 176)'],
 'cv_scores': ['[0.71936929 0.75262699 0.77660679 0.85333625 0.76398875]',
  '[0.79227296 0.82675175 0.83723801 0.92502134 0.82625185]',
  '[0.82134069 0.84987581 0.86420576 0.93398567 0.84150328]',
  '[0.83244816 0.86689598 0.87095624 0.9445071  0.85839512]',
  '[0.84192526 0.87788764 0.87939774 0.95181742 0.86563099]']}
)

df.head(2)
    feature_idx           cv_scores
0         (4,)      [0.71936929 0.75262699 0.77660679 0.85333625 0...
1      (4, 15)      [0.79227296 0.82675175 0.83723801 0.92502134 0...
```

The column `cv_scores` contains string for the scores of 5-fold, so for example.

```py
>>> sub_df.iloc[0]['cv_scores']
'[0.71936929 0.75262699 0.77660679 0.85333625 0.76398875]'

>>> type(sub_df.iloc[0]['cv_scores'])
 str
```

I would like to add a column `avg_score`  for the average score of each feature (`cv_scores / 5`).

Since `cv_scores` is a string, I need a way to convert this column to array of float, to derive the intended column.

**Expected results**

```py
>>> df_result
             feature_idx    cv_scores                                          avg_score
0                  (4,)     [0.71936929 0.75262699 0.77660679 0.85333625 0...   0.773186
1               (4, 15)     [0.79227296 0.82675175 0.83723801 0.92502134 0...   0.841507
2            (1, 4, 15)     [0.82134069 0.84987581 0.86420576 0.93398567 0...   0.862182
3       (1, 4, 15, 176)     [0.83244816 0.86689598 0.87095624 0.9445071 0...    0.874641
4   (1, 4, 15, 89, 176)     [0.84192526 0.87788764 0.87939774 0.95181742 0...   0.883332
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.fromstring`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) to convert your strings:

```
def str_to_mean(s):
    return np.fromstring(s[1:-1], sep=' ').mean()

df['avg_score'] = df['cv_scores'].apply(str_to_mean)
```

Alternative with [`str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html), [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html), and [`groupby.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.mean.html):

```
df['avg_score'] = (pd.to_numeric(df['cv_scores'].str.extractall(r'(\d+.?\d*)')[0],
                                 errors='coerce')
                     .groupby(level=0).mean()
                  )
```

Output:

```
           feature_idx                                          cv_scores  avg_score
0                 (4,)  [0.71936929 0.75262699 0.77660679 0.85333625 0...   0.773186
1              (4, 15)  [0.79227296 0.82675175 0.83723801 0.92502134 0...   0.841507
2           (1, 4, 15)  [0.82134069 0.84987581 0.86420576 0.93398567 0...   0.862182
3      (1, 4, 15, 176)  [0.83244816 0.86689598 0.87095624 0.9445071  0...   0.874641
4  (1, 4, 15, 89, 176)  [0.84192526 0.87788764 0.87939774 0.95181742 0...   0.883332
```

Comment: Interesting....you make my day!